# Is this a bounded sequence ? (about continued fraction)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

Represent $\sqrt{2}$ in the form $$\sqrt{2}=1+\frac{8}{A_1+\displaystyle\frac{8}{A_2+\displaystyle\frac{8}{A_3+\ddots}}},$$
where $A_n$ is a positive integer and $A_n \geq 8$ for all $n$. So we have $A_1=19$, $A_2=25$, $A_3=15$ and so on. 
Is the sequence $\left(A_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ bounded?  How to proof? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why??????????????????????????????

Comment: I would think not.

Comment: Here are some more terms: http://oeis.org/A087951

Comment: Help me please.